# Sqlalchemy won't load for Kaggle notebooks

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, kaggle

I have been able to connect to a db2 database using sqlalchemy for notebooks on IBM Watson, Microsoft Azure, and Cognitive Class. The problem is I've failed to connect when using my kaggle notebooks. Since I want to have all my notebooks on kaggle, I would like to fix this.

Here is the error I get:

> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
>    postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname or an existing connection:
>   dict_keys([]) Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example: postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

These are the credentials I'm using:

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://user:pswd@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-04.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB
```

Relevant packages installed:

ibm-db 3.0.1
ibm-db-sa 0.3.5
SQLAlchemy 1.3.16

!jupyter --version

jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 5.5.0
qtconsole        : 4.7.3
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.1
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : 1.2.10
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3

`sys.version`

> 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 23 2020, 23:03:20) 
>   [GCC 7.3.0]

%Sql Magic Modules:

ipython-sql: 0.3.9
pandasql: 0.7.3
SQLAlchemy: 1.3.16
sqlparse: 0.3.1

Operating System Details:

Windows 10 Home
Version 1909
Installed on 6/12/19
OS Build 18363.836

Yes, I can connect using `ibm_db.connect()` from within Jupyter notebooks on Kaggle, and I can run SQL queries from there, and also through the console, but I don't know how to access python outside of the kaggle notebooks, which are in the cloud. I don't have a local version of python or jupyter notebooks installed.

I have tried the following:

```
import sqlalchemy`
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://user:pswd@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-04.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB')
```

And I get the following error:

> NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa

But the sqlalchemy and related modules are loaded (see above.)

OS Name:

`os.name` returns posix.

---

There is a '+' but it is the same password I use to connect to IBM Watson, Microsoft Azure, and Cognitive Class without a problem.

---

`!pip show ibm_db` returns the following:

> Name: ibm-db
>   Version: 3.0.1
>   Summary: Python DBI driver for DB2 (LUW, zOS, i5) and IDS
>   Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db/
>   Author: IBM Application Development Team
>   Author-email: opendev@us.ibm.com
>   License: Apache License 2.0
>   Location: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   Requires:
>   Required-by: ibm-db-sa

---

`!pip show ibm_db_sa` returns the following:

> Name: ibm-db-sa
>   Version: 0.3.5
>   Summary: SQLAlchemy support for IBM Data Servers
>   Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db_sa/
>   Author: IBM Application Development Team
>   Author-email: opendev@us.ibm.com
>   License: Apache License 2.0
>   Location: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   Requires: ibm-db, sqlalchemy
>   Required-by:

---

`!conda list` includes the following in results:

> ibm-db 3.0.1 pypi_0    pypi
>   ibm-db-sa 0.3.5 pypi_0    pypi

`!conda show ibm_db` returns the following:

> ERROR: unknown command "conda"

`!conda show ibm_db_sa` returns the following:

> CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda show'.

---

`!conda list` includes pyodbc 4.0.30 py37he1b5a44_0 conda-forge

`from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry` was successful.

`registry.register( 'ibm_db_sa', 'ibm_db_sa', 'ibm_db_sa.ibm_db.DB2Dialect_ibm_db')` was successful.

But I still cannot connect.

---

All components are running in the cloud. Nothing is local.

---

As a test, I was able on kaggle to successfully run sqlalchemy and the sql_ext using sqlite and a simple in-memory database. I created a new notebook using the following and was able to run queries after creating a sample table and sample data:

```
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite://
```

Since I'm able to connect to db2 on other notebook cloud hosts (IBM Watson Studio, Azure, Cognitive Class) and I'm able to connect to non-db2 databases on kaggle, it would appear that the problem is with trying to connect ONLY to db2 and ONLY when I'm using notebooks hosted on kaggle.

---

Using a blank notebook in kaggle, I input these lines of code and get the connection error:

```
%load_ext sql
```

> The sql extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
>     %reload_ext sql

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://user:pswd@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-04.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB
```

> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
>                  postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
>                  or an existing connection: dict_keys(['sqlite://'])
>   Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa
>   Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
>                  postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
>                  or an existing connection: dict_keys(['sqlite://'])

Using another blank notebook, I input these lines of code and can connect successfully to a sqlite in-memory database:

```
%load_ext sql
```

> The sql extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
>     %reload_ext sql

```
%sql sqlite://
```

> 'Connected: @None'

With the sqlite, I can then perform queries.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: It should. I haven't seen any documentation to the contrary. I can import the ibm-db 3.0.1, ibm-db-sa 0.3.5, but I can't seem to get them to work. I was able to get sqlite to work with an in-memory db. See the post.

Comment: That's correct. I can get to db2 using ibm_db in kaggle notebook, I just can't get to it using ibm_db_sa.

Comment: FYI. RHEL 7.8 , anaconda 4.8.3, python 3.7.6 with jupyter notebook, `import sqlalchemy` and `import ibm_db_sa` run successfully, `%load_ext sql`  works, `%env DATABASE_URL=ibm_db_sa://user:passwd@host:port/dbname` then the `%sql select...`   all work correctly for me. This is with everything locally (i know for you everything is cloud based but I'm trying to simplify to make progress). Can you confirm the exact steps you follow in a blank kaggle notebook?

Comment: See the post for an update. BTW, IBM cloud support says that it is a problem with kaggle because the import is failing before any attempt to connect is made.

Comment: Make sure that "Internet" is toggled on on settings in kaggle notebook. To install I just used `!pip install ibm_db`

Comment: FYI: I can recreate the symptom with a kaggle notebook (cloud). When installing ibm_db_sa (with conda install , yields version 0.3.5) I see a message warning about "the environment is inconsistent" and "the following packages are causing the inconsistency" (long list of them) but install proceeded because I used "--yes". First clue? Will try with local docker kaggle-python image, see what can be debugged.

Comment: FYI: Using the docker CPU-only image ( from gcr.io/kaggle-images/python ), the ibm_db_sa and %sql magic work correctly in a jupyter notebook in a container. So the symptom seems specific to the cloud container. I cannot tell the difference(s) between the cloud container and the container that results from using gcr.io/kaggle-images/python .  Need to debug on the cloud based container.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, there appears to be an environemental problem on Kaggle when trying to connect to a db2 database using sqlalchemy. The problem doesn't exist when using notebooks locally in Jupyterlab, on IBM Watson, Microsoft Azure, and Cognitive Class. So, at this point I consider this question resolved. Thanks @mao for all the effort.